# Utilities.getOutputMediaFileUri(Utilities.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) function not working in android Oreo for opening the camera in Android Studio

Tags: android-8.0-oreo

/* getOutputMediaFileUri() */

public static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        //return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));

```
    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(Application.getContext(), Application.getContext().getPackageName() + ".com.mentcom.mentp.provider", getOutputMediaFile(type));
}
```